# Interesting SQL Sorting Issue

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, logic

It's crunch time, deadline for my most recent contract is coming in two days and almost everything is complete and working fine (knock on wood) except for one issue.

In one of my stored procedures, I'm needing to return a result set as follows.

```
group_id      name
--------      --------
A101          Craig
A102          Craig
Z101          Craig
Z102          Craig
A101          Jim
A102          Jim
Z101          Jim
Z102          Jim
B101          Andy
B102          Andy
Z101          Andy
Z102          Andy
```

The names need to be sorted by the first character of the group id and also include the Z101/Z102 entries. By sorting strictly by the group id, I get a result set as follows:

```
group_id      name
--------      --------
A101          Craig
A102          Craig
A101          Jim
A102          Jim
B101          Andy
B102          Andy
Z101          Andy
Z102          Andy
Z101          Craig
Z102          Craig
Z101          Jim
Z102          Jim
```

I really can't think of a solution that doesn't involve me making a cursor and bloating the stored procedure up more than it already is. I'm sure a great mind out there has an elegant solution and I'm eager to see what the community can come up with.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Edit: Let me expand :) I'm sorry, it's late and I'm coffee addled.

The above result set is a special case for a special type of data entry. Being transparent, we're making an election based website and these are going to be candidates sorted by office, name, and then district.

Most offices have multiple districts in them except for district positions like magistrate/coroner, which will have only one. The Z comes in as the "district" for absentee machine and absentee paper votes.

The non-magistrate positions can be sorted by name first, as they are all grouped together. However, the existing system lists all magistrates in a huge clump of information, when they should be sorted by individual districts. This is where the issue lies.

To protect my pride, I want to add that I had no control over the normalization of the database. It was given to me by the client.

Here's the order clause of my stored procedure, if it helps:

```
    ORDER BY    candidate.party,
            candidate.ballot_name,  
CASE WHEN       candidate.district_type = 'MAG' THEN LEFT(votecount.precinct_id, 1) END,
        candidate.last_name,
        candidate.first_name,
        precinct.name
```

**Edit 2**: Here's where I currently stand (1:43 A.M.) -

I'm using a suggestion below to create a conditional inner join as follows:

```
    IF          candidate.district_type = 'MAG'
BEGIN
    (
        SELECT candidate.id AS candidate_id, candidate.last_name, LEFT(votecount.precinct_id, 1) AS district, votecount.precinct_id
        FROM candidate
        INNER JOIN votecount
        ON votecount.candidate_id = candidate.id
        GROUP BY name
    ) mag_order
    INNER JOIN      mag_order
    ON              mag_order.candidate_id = candidate.id
END
```

and then I'll sort it by mag_order.district, candidate.precinct_id, candidate.last_name.

For some reason I'm getting a SQL error when aliasing the ( SELECT ) as mag_order. Anyone see anything wrong with the code? I can't for the life of me. Sorry this is a bit tangential.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the requirement. If you want to sort by the first character of group_id, is the output not correct? Where did the combination of `Z101` and `Craig` come from, or... where did it go in the second table there? Can you please post some sample complete input, the output you want, and the output you actually get, since I suspect you're only posting parts of the data and cutting it off.

Comment: I'm going to take a crack at rewording your criteria, please post a comment (or update your question): You want to order by the first character of the group_id, which means A comes before B comes before C, etc. And then for A, you want to order by the name, which means Andy would come before Craig (except that Andy doesn't have any A's). However, once you've decided that you're onto Craig, you also want all his Z's.

Comment: I think `ORDER BY name, group_id` is all you need, but it depends on if it matters more that the Craig/etc grouping as at the top.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Actually if you look carefully it is more complicated than that

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Yeah, essentially I need it to order strictly by group_id's first character and include Z as an arbitrary group_id at the end of that result. It's convoluted =-/

Comment: What is the source data please? I suspect you don't actually have a "z" group, no?

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase that. It would be easier to generate the Z grouping on the fly...

Comment: Well, the data is coming from a table that tracks vote counts, so the Z grouping is actually in the database and needs to be tracked separately than the districts.

I think the route I'll go after messing around with it is switching Z101/Z102 to [district_id]AB1/[district_id]AB2. This won't screw with anything and everything will display as expected then. It'd take far less time than what I've already put into trying to sort this junk.

I'd still be interested in a solution for future reference though. This is a hell of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT g1.group_id, g1.name
FROM 
    groups g1
        INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  MIN(group_id), name
        FROM groups
        GROUP BY name
    ) g2 on g1.name = g2.name
ORDER BY g2.group_id, g1.name, g1.group_id
```

Comment: This solution is very close. The only issue with it is that what I'm talking about above is a special case in a large set of returned data. About 20% of returned data needs to be handled in the way I'm asking, where the other 80% is a simple [order by name, group_id].

I'm going to play around with your solution a bit and try to make it fit. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @rofly, the sorted set you have has Craig, Jim, Andy.  I'm not sure how this jives with 80% by "name, group_id".  Perhaps a larger dataset sample and expected result is needed (along with test data ddl/inserts).

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY name DESC, SUBSTR(group_id,1), group_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT groupId, name
FROM table
ORDER BY getFirstGroupId(name), name, groupId
```

Then your getFirstGroupId() function would return the first groupId for that name

```
SELECT MIN(groupId)
FROM groupTable
WHERE name = @name
```